# Macro no reconoce celda BuscarX

Tags: excel, macros, porcentaje, paso-por-valor

En el excel que he diseñado para mis entrenamientos, quiero copiar el valor de E4 de la hoja inicial (denominada "Formulario") a otra, en función del % indicado en E29.

[image: Hoja con valores a copiar (celda E4]

Esta celda E29 contiene una fórmula =BuscarX que busca el valor máximo de la columna D (en este ejemplo: 0,74 de D8 y D12) en una tabla donde extrae el % al que corresponde (busca 0,74 o el siguiente valor mayor, que es 0,76 y corresponde al 62,5%).

[image: Tabla de búsqueda de %]

Consecuentemente, quiero copiar el valor de D4 a otra hoja (denominada "PRESS BANCA") para su análisis. Debe copiarse en la celda adyacente al % que buscó la celda E29 de la hoja inicial (en este caso, a de copiarse en D14), pero aquí viene el problema porque el macro no reconoce el valor de la celda E29 y por tanto no copia la celda D4 (37,5) de la hoja Formulario a la D14 de la hoja PRESS BANCA. El resto de datos del macro sí son copiados con normalidad.

[image: Valor sin copiar (37,5) junto al % correspondiente (62,5%), en celda D14]

A continuación el macro vba:
[image: Macro]

Cabe mencionar que anteriormente la celda E29 contenía una fórmula =SI en vez de =BUSCARX, que cambié por ser más larga y engorrosa, pero sí reconocía y copiaba los datos. Es decir, el cambio de fórmula ha producido este problema, pero desconozco el motivo puesto que, aparentemente todo es correcto y el macro no ha sido modificado, por lo que debería continuar copiando los valores.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No vamos a poder ayudar en nada si tu codigo esta como imagen, nadie va a poder copiarlo para probarlo. Mas alla de eso, lo depuraste a ver que valores estan viniendo en el rango??

Comment: Probaste a quitar el .Value? Es decir, sustituye "ElseIf Range("E29").Value = "62,5%" " por "ElseIf Range("E29") = "62,5%"

Comment: Sí, probé con y sin .Value, y tampoco reconoce la celda.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Por favor, los códigos **nunca** como imagen, sino como texto. En relación a tu consulta, tiene toda la pinta de que BUSCARX te está devolviendo un valor numérico y al hacer algo tipo `Range("E29").value = "62,5%"' estás comparando un texto con un número. ` ¿Probaste con algo tipo `=0.625`? ¿Qué tipo de dato devuelve E29 si haces `Debug.print Range("E29").value?`

Comment: Perdón por los códigos en imagen, lo desconocía. La opción Debug.print no soluciona, pero cambiar el formato de la celda a números (0,625) sí hace el copiado. Sin embargo, querría que reflejara el porcentaje, que es lo que realmente representa ese dato del entrenamiento, se les ocurre alguna otra alternativa? Muchas gracias no obstante por su ayuda

Comment: *La opción Debug.print no soluciona* Claro, pero necesitamos esa opción para saber cómo lo está leyendo VBA en origen. El resultado te saldrá en la ventana inmediato. Necesitamos ese valor para saber cómo tratarlo